# Unknown property error - from Apex Page save

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardsetcontroller, selectoption

Please find below my apex controller for which I am getting unknown property error for TableExampleController.CISubClass.Id when I try compile my corresponding page with it.

I am not getting the reason for the error when controller is compiled fine. Below i have the page.

**Apex code:**

```
public with sharing class TableExampleController {
    // CI and selection set/variables
    private list<CISubClass> CIList {get; set;}
    private set<Id> CISelectedSet;
    public Integer CISelectedCount {get; set;}
    public String SelectedOneCI {get; set;}

    // selection and filter 
    public list<String> AlphaList {get; set;}
    public String AlphaFilter {get; set;}
    public String SearchName {get; set;}
    public String SearchBillingAddress {get; set;} 
    private String SaveSearchName;
    private String SaveSearchBillingAddress;
    private String QueryCI;

    // display sort and number
    public String RecPerPage {get; set;}
    public list<SelectOption> RecPerPageOption {get; set;}  
    public String SortFieldSave;

    /***
    * TableExampleController - Constructor initialization
    ***/
    public TableExampleController(){
        CIList = new list<CISubClass>();
        CISelectedSet = new set<Id>();

        //records for page initialization
        RecPerPageOption = new list<SelectOption>();
        RecPerPageOption.add(new SelectOption('10','10'));
        RecPerPageOption.add(new SelectOption('25','25'));
        RecPerPageOption.add(new SelectOption('50','50'));
        RecPerPageOption.add(new SelectOption('100','100'));
        RecPerPageOption.add(new SelectOption('200','200'));
        RecPerPage = '10'; //default records per page

        // initialization alpha list
        AlphaList = new list<String> {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Other', 'All'};
            SortFieldSave = SortField;

        // alpha filter, use page parameter or set default to all
        if (apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('alpha') == null) {
            AlphaFilter = 'All';
        } else {
            AlphaFilter = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('alpha');
        }

        // list generation
        BuildQuery();  
    }

    /***
    * StdSetControllerCI - paging through the CI list
    ***/ 
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController StdSetControllerCI {
        get {
            if(StdSetControllerCI == null) {
                StdSetControllerCI = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(QueryCI));
                // sets the number of records in each page set
                StdSetControllerCI.setPageSize(Integer.valueOf(RecPerPage));
            }
            return StdSetControllerCI;
        }
        set;
    }

    /***
    * getCurrentCIList - return an CI list for the table
    ***/  
    public list<CISubClass> getCurrentCIList() {
        UpdateCISelectedSet();

        CIList = new list<CISubClass>();
        for (Compliance_Incident_abv__c a : (list<Compliance_Incident_abv__c>)StdSetControllerCI.getRecords()) {
            CIList.add(new CISubClass(a, CISelectedSet.contains(a.Id)));
        }
        return CIList;
    }

    /***
    * UpdateCISelectedSet - add/remove CIs from the selected CI id list
    ***/
    public void UpdateCISelectedSet(){
        for(CISubClass a : CIList ){
            if(a.aCheckBox == true) {
                CISelectedSet.add(a.aCI.Id);
            } else {
                if(CISelectedSet.contains(a.aCI.Id)) {
                    CISelectedSet.remove(a.aCI.Id);
                }
            }
        }  
        CISelectedCount = CISelectedSet.size();
    }

    /***
    * ClearCISelectedSet - remove selected CIs and initialize counter
    ***/
    public PageReference ClearAll(){
        CIList.clear();
        CISelectedSet.clear();
        CISelectedCount = 0;
        SearchName = '';
        SearchBillingAddress = '';
        SaveSearchName = '';
        SaveSearchBillingAddress = '';
        AlphaFilter = 'All';

        BuildQuery();

        return null;
    }

    /***
    * SearchCI - set search criteria fields and refresh CI table
    ***/
    public PageReference SearchCI() {
        SaveSearchName = SearchName;
        SaveSearchBillingAddress = SearchBillingAddress;

        BuildQuery();

        return null;
    }

    /***
    * BuildQuery - build query command for list selection change
    ***/
    public void BuildQuery() {
        StdSetControllerCI = null;
        String QueryWhere = '';

        if (AlphaFilter == null || AlphaFilter.trim().length() == 0) {
            AlphaFilter = 'All';
        }

        QueryCI = 'SELECT Id, Publish_Date_abv__c,Name, Incident_Type_abv__c, Status_abv__c,  Rep_abv__c, Rep_Franchise_abv__c, RecordTypeID, No_Of_Transactions_abv__c FROM Compliance_Incident_abv__c'; 

        if (AlphaFilter == 'Other') {
            QueryWhere = BuildWhere(QueryWhere, '(' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SortField) + ' < \'A\' OR ' + 
                                    String.escapeSingleQuotes(SortField) + ' > \'Z\') AND (NOT ' + 
                                    String.escapeSingleQuotes(SortField) + ' LIKE \'Z%\') ');
        } else if (AlphaFilter != 'All') {
            QueryWhere = BuildWhere(QueryWhere, '(' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SortField) + ' LIKE \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(AlphaFilter) + '%\')' );
        }

        if (SaveSearchName != null) {
            QueryWhere = BuildWhere(QueryWhere, ' (Name LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SaveSearchName) + '%\')');
        }
        if (SaveSearchBillingAddress != null) {
            QueryWhere = BuildWhere(QueryWhere, '((BillingStreet LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SaveSearchBillingAddress) + '%\') or' +
                                    ' (BillingCity LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SaveSearchBillingAddress) + '%\') or' +
                                    ' (BillingState LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SaveSearchBillingAddress) + '%\') or' +
                                    ' (BillingPostalCode LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SaveSearchBillingAddress) + '%\') or' +
                                    ' (BillingCountry LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SaveSearchBillingAddress) + '%\'))');
        }

        QueryCI += QueryWhere;
        QueryCI += ' ORDER BY ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SortField) + ' ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(SortDirection) + ' LIMIT 10000';

        system.debug('QueryCI:' + QueryCI);
    }

    /***
    * BuildWhere - build soql string for where criteria 
    ***/
    public String BuildWhere(String QW, String Cond) {
        if (QW == '') {
            return ' WHERE ' + Cond;
        } else {
            return QW + ' AND ' + Cond;
        }
    }

    /***
    * SortDirection - return sort direction. Default ascending(asc)
    ***/
    public String SortDirection {
        get { if (SortDirection == null) {  SortDirection = 'asc'; } return SortDirection;  }
        set;
    }

    /***
    * SortField - return sort by field. Default to Name
    ***/
    public String SortField {
        get { if (SortField == null) {SortField = 'Name'; } return SortField;  }
        set; 
    }

    /***
    * SortToggle - toggles the sorting of query from asc<-->desc
    ***/
    public void SortToggle() {
        SortDirection = SortDirection.equals('asc') ? 'desc NULLS LAST' : 'asc';
        // reset alpha filter and sort sequence when sorted field is changed
        if (SortFieldSave != SortField) {
            SortDirection = 'asc';
            AlphaFilter = 'All';
            SortFieldSave = SortField;
        }
        // run the query again
        BuildQuery();
    }

    /***
    * DoSomethingOne - do something with one selected CI
    ***/
    public PageReference DoSomethingOne() {
        system.debug('SelectedOneCI: ' + SelectedOneCI);
        return null;
    }

    /***
    * DoSomethingMany - do something with many selected CIs
    ***/
    public PageReference DoSomethingMany() {
        for (Id CIId : CISelectedSet) {
            system.debug('Checked: ' + CIId);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /***
    * CISubClass - Sub-Class to hold CI and checkbox for the table
    ***/
    public class CISubClass {
        public Boolean aCheckBox {get;set;}
        public Compliance_Incident_abv__c aCI {get;set;}

        // sub-class initialization
        public CISubClass(Compliance_Incident_abv__c a, Boolean chk){
            aCI = a;
            aCheckBox = chk;
        }
    }
}
```

**Apex Page**

```
<apex:page controller="TableExampleController">
 <style type="text/css">
.loading-icon {
   background-image: url(/img/loading.gif);
   width: 16px;
   height: 16px;
}

a.alpha-link {
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 91%;
   padding: 0 4px;
   color: #015BA7 !important;
}

a.alpha-link+a.alpha-link {
   border-left: 1px solid #CFCECE;
}

a.alpha-link:hover {
   background-color: #e0f5fc !important;
}

a.alpha-select {
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #C6E1FF;
   color: #000000 !important;
}

.search-block {
   text-align: center;
}

.search-block input {
   margin: 0px 15px 0px 5px;
}

.search-block-button {
   min-width: 110px;
}

.process-block {
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 10px;
}

.process-block input {
   margin: 0px 15px;
}

.process-block-button {
   min-width: 110px;
}

.page-buttons input {
   min-width: 110px;
}
</style>

   <apex:form id="TheForm">
      <!-- ***************************** -->
      <!-- Search Criteria     -->         
      <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
         <div class="search-block">
            <div style="display: inline-table">
               <span>Name:</span>
               <apex:inputText value="{!SearchName}" />
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-table">
               <span>Billing Address:</span>
               <apex:inputText value="{!SearchBillingAddress}" />
            </div>
            <apex:commandButton styleClass="search-block-button" value="Search" action="{!SearchCI}" rerender="TablePanel"
               status="TableUpdateStatus" />
         </div>

         <div class="process-block">
            <apex:actionStatus id="ProcessButtonStatus">
               <apex:facet name="stop">
                  <apex:outputPanel >
                     <apex:commandButton styleClass="process-block-button" value="Process Selected" action="{!DoSomethingMany}"
                        status="ProcessButtonStatus" rerender="nothing" />
                     <apex:commandButton styleClass="process-block-button" value="Clear All" action="{!ClearAll}"
                        rerender="TheForm,TablePanel" />
                  </apex:outputPanel>
               </apex:facet>
               <apex:facet name="start">
                  <apex:outputPanel >
                     <apex:commandButton styleClass="process-block-button" value="Processing..." disabled="true" />
                     <apex:commandButton styleClass="process-block-button" value="Processing..." disabled="true" />
                  </apex:outputPanel>
               </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
         </div>
      </apex:pageBlock>

      <!-- ************************* -->
      <!-- search results table   -->   
      <apex:pageBlock id="TablePanel">
         <div>
            <span class="page-buttons" style="float: left; margin-bottom: 5px;"> <apex:commandButton disabled="{!!StdSetControllerCI.hasprevious}" value="Previous" action="{!StdSetControllerCI.previous}"
                  rerender="TablePanel" /> <apex:commandButton disabled="{!!StdSetControllerCI.hasnext}" value="Next"
                  action="{!StdSetControllerCI.next}" rerender="TablePanel" />
            </span>
            <!-- alphabet selection -->
            <span style="float: right; margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;"> <apex:repeat value="{!AlphaList}" var="a">
                  <apex:commandLink value="{!a}" action="{!BuildQuery}" rerender="TablePanel"
                     styleClass="alpha-link{!if(AlphaFilter=a,' alpha-select','')}" status="TableUpdateStatus">
                     <apex:param name="AlphaFilter" value="{!a}" assignTo="{!AlphaFilter}" />
                  </apex:commandLink>
               </apex:repeat>
            </span>
         </div>

         <div style="clear: both;"></div>

         <apex:actionStatus id="TableUpdateStatus">
            <apex:inputHidden value="{!AlphaFilter}" id="hiddenField" />
            <!-- loading message -->
            <apex:facet name="start">
               <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="message infoM4">
                  <apex:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="messageTable" columnClasses="messageCell" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                     <apex:panelGroup >
                        <img class="loading-icon" src="/s.gif" />
                     </apex:panelGroup>
                     <apex:panelGroup >
                        <div class="messageText">Please wait...</div>
                     </apex:panelGroup>
                  </apex:panelGrid>
               </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:facet>

            <!-- CI table -->
            <apex:facet name="stop">
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CurrentCIList}" var="a">
                  <apex:column >
                     <apex:commandLink styleClass="alpha-link" action="{!DoSomethingOne}">
                        <apex:param value="{!a.Id}" assignTo="{!SelectedOneCI}" />Select</apex:commandLink>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:outputPanel id="SelectedCount">
                           <div style="text-align: center;">
                              <apex:outputText value="Selected" />
                              <br />
                              <apex:outputText value="{!CISelectedCount}" />
                           </div>
                        </apex:outputPanel>
                     </apex:facet>
                     <div style="text-align: center;">
                        <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!a.aCheckBox}" id="check-box">
                           <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="SelectedCount" action="{!UpdateCISelectedSet}" />
                           </apex:inputcheckbox>
                     </div>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!SortToggle}" rerender="TablePanel" status="TableUpdateStatus">
                           <apex:param name="SortField" value="Report Date" assignTo="{!SortField}" />
                           <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Compliance_Incident_abv__c.Fields.Publish_Date_abv__c.Label}{!IF(SortField=='Publish_Date_abv__c',IF(SortDirection='asc','▲','▼'),'')}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputField value="{!a.Publish_Date_abv__c}" />
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!SortToggle}" rerender="TablePanel" status="TableUpdateStatus">
                           <apex:param name="SortField" value="Compliance Incident Name" assignTo="{!SortField}" />
                           <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Compliance_Incident_abv__c.Fields.Name.Label}{!IF(SortField=='Name',IF(SortDirection='asc','▲','▼'),'')}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>

                      <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.Id}" target="_blank">{!a.Name}</apex:outputlink>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!SortToggle}" rerender="TablePanel" status="TableUpdateStatus">
                           <apex:param name="SortField" value="Incident Type" assignTo="{!SortField}" />
                           <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Compliance_Incident_abv__c.Fields.Incident_Type_abv__c.Label}{!IF(SortField=='Incident_Type_abv__c',IF(SortDirection='asc','▲','▼'),'')}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputField value="{!a.Incident_Type_abv__c}" />
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!SortToggle}" rerender="TablePanel" status="TableUpdateStatus">
                           <apex:param name="SortField" value="Total Transactions" assignTo="{!SortField}" />
                           <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Compliance_Incident_abv__c.Fields.No_Of_Transactions_abv__c.Label}{!IF(SortField==' No_Of_Transactions_abv__c',IF(SortDirection='asc','▲','▼'),'')}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputField value="{!a.No_Of_Transactions_abv__c}" />
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!SortToggle}" rerender="TablePanel" status="TableUpdateStatus">
                           <apex:param name="SortField" value="Report Status" assignTo="{!SortField}" />
                           <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Compliance_Incident_abv__c.Fields.Status_abv__c.Label}{!IF(SortField=='Status_abv__c',IF(SortDirection='asc','▲','▼'),'')}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputField value="{!a.Status_abv__c}" />
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!SortToggle}" rerender="TablePanel" status="TableUpdateStatus">
                           <apex:param name="SortField" value="Representative" assignTo="{!SortField}" />
                           <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Compliance_Incident_abv__c.Fields.Rep_abv__c.Label}{!IF(SortField=='Rep_abv__c',IF(SortDirection='asc','▲','▼'),'')}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                      <apex:outputLink value="/{!a.Id}" target="_blank">{!a.Rep_abv__c}</apex:outputlink>
                  </apex:column>
                   <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:commandLink action="{!SortToggle}" rerender="TablePanel" status="TableUpdateStatus">
                           <apex:param name="SortField" value="Representative Franschise" assignTo="{!SortField}" />
                           <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Compliance_Incident_abv__c.Fields.Rep_Franchise_abv__c.Label}{!IF(SortField=='Rep_Franchise_abv__c',IF(SortDirection='asc','▲','▼'),'')}" />
                        </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputField value="{!a.Rep_Franchise_abv__c}" />
                  </apex:column>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:facet>
         </apex:actionStatus>
         <div style="margin-top: 5px;">
            <apex:outputText value="Number of Records per Page: " />
            <apex:selectList value="{!RecPerPage}" size="1">
               <apex:selectOptions value="{!RecPerPageOption}" />
               <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!BuildQuery}" reRender="TablePanel" status="TableUpdateStatus" />
            </apex:selectList>
         </div>
      </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looked into the wrapper class.

You have record variable in wrapper class

but in VF page you are trying to access the object Id directly

ie.

```
 <apex:commandLink styleClass="alpha-link" action="{!DoSomethingOne}">
      <apex:param value="{!a.Id}" assignTo="{!SelectedOneCI}" />Select
  </apex:commandLink>
```

Here you are accessing a.Id but a is the wrapper instance

You have to use like a.aCI.Id

```
  <apex:commandLink styleClass="alpha-link" action="{!DoSomethingOne}">
     <apex:param value="{!a.aCI.Id}" assignTo="{!SelectedOneCI}" />Select
  </apex:commandLink>
```